# Contacts phone numbers disappeared after sync to google

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, contacts, sync, google

After synchronising with Google, all contacts that have phone numbers associated with them disappeared.

I tried to enter a new contact just to test this. If I sync again the new entry disappears as well. How can it be recovered?

My phone is a Galaxy Note II

Comment: This bug is still present. Android 5.0.1 Samsung S4 here. But in my case if I reenter the contacts, the second sync was ok. Sync should NOT delete your contacts without warning. Very bogus.

Comment: The same happened to me, same Android version and same device of Pedro77. I lost hundreds of contacts because of this bug. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Did you clear Contacts Storage?

Settings > Applications > General Applications > All (at the top) > Contacts Storage >  force stop   > clear data

then
Bring up "Contacts" you will then see "You don't have any contacts to display" > press Menu button >  Accounts > choose account to sync (your gmail account) > Sync

Comment: where is this? android or google/gmail? i couldn't find it in either one.

Comment: @zz Android settings you will have select ALL at the top; otherwise you will not see Contacts (not the one that has to be cleared), but Contacts Storage which you will also see would be the one to clear.  The next line refers to bringing up the  Contacts application which is a preinstalled application which is populated from gmail contacts, with the intent to synchronize from your Gmail desktop contacts.  But in the next answer you have stated that you don't have Gmail contacts so this sort of becomes mute, if true.  I would try this first. Other answer my desktop has "My contacts" not All ...

Comment: Just clearing the data was enough to solve my problem on Android 4.4. Thanks!

Comment: This does not solve the problem mentioned in the question because the contacts were NOT copied from the Android device to the Google account, they were simply deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Google can restore your contacts from the last thirty days.  This is for your desktop computer, and would probably propagate into your  Android as well, if Android is not fixed after fixing your desktop contacts, fix those on Android with our other answers, afterwards.

**Google search:**  lost gmail contacts

- [**Restore contacts - Gmail Help**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1069522?hl=en), You can restore your contact list to the state it was in at any point within the past 30 days.

  [**How to Restore Google Contacts:** 6 Steps (with Pictures) - wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Restore-Google-Contacts)

Comment: Since the contats are only on the cell phone and after sync they disappear. Restore using gmail is useless, the contacts have never been there.

Comment: This answer is useless, as Pedro77 mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Ensure "contacts to display" is set to "all contacts" (under the settings in your contacts app). This ensures you will see contacts from your Google account.

It would he good to validate your Google Contacts data by going to http://www.google.com/contacts. Verifying that all the data is there confirms that the issue is with your phone's display, not the data.

Comment: the problem is I don't have any contacts in my gmail account since I started it recently. I wanted the google account to save the contacts I have on the Galaxy. maybe it went the other way and copied the zero contacts I have in the google account to my phone memory. question is can it be reversed.

Comment: This answer is useless, as explained by ZZ productions