# New contacts added to my phone get deleted after sync with my Google account

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account

Any time I add a new contact to my Google contacts, the second I turn on my WiFi it gets disappeared. It's been for over a month on Android 4.3 and 4.4 I have tested. This is new and I have not had this before. I guess the problem lies with the synchronization with Google account.

Note that this is not the case with Phone or SIM card contacts. That's why I am sure the problem lies somewhere in sync.

Is there any official issue that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Did you mean the contact is deleted when you say disappeared?

Comment: Yes Yes Yes. Deleted from my contacts.

Comment: I think you need to filter out the contacts in Contacts menu. There's a filter option if you see clearly. Click on the particular Google account and then select 'All contacts'. One thing must be made clear that contacts won't be deleted themselves.

Comment: I know about that filter and it was one of the first things I checked. In fact 3 of my friends with different android have the same problem as me. I am sure it is not from my side. I am absolutely sure the problem is with the contact sync. When Android wants to sync my contacts with my Google account contacts, it thinks those contacts that are on my phone which do not exist on my Google account it thinks they have been DELETED from account (not added on my android) so it deletes the contacts from the phone.

Comment: Same here! Android 5.0.1! No solution?

Comment: Same question (no answer up to now): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82717/contacts-phone-numbers-disappeared-after-sync-to-google

Comment: Same here with Moto G2 4G marshmallow... maybe is a configuration issue?

Answer (score 1):

solved!

I had the problem for a while, I now tried to add the contact to another google account (I have 2) - this time to the main account the phone is registered on.

The contacts have yet to disappear!

hope this will continue working (I know this isn't the best solution, cause what if you don't have 2 accounts?!)